# trigonometric substitution in two way

Tags: integration, derivatives, trigonometry, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

Hi this is one of question that i have got stumbling on.

This is just simple question using trigonometric substitution.

[image]

i do understand the solution process.

But What i wanna know is that it uses sin for finding solution but what if use cos instead?
[image]

my approach concluded into -arccos(x/4)+c which is say wrong answer but still if i differentiate it, it will be as same as original function in integral, which means it is also correct answer!

Guess i am missing some silly simple thing. Hope someone can help me out

Comment: They're equivalent up to a constant (+C term), as $\text{arcsin}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \text{arccos}(x)$.

Comment: You could upvote an answer that you like by clicking the up-arrow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that when you integrate a function you get MANY antiderivatives. That's why there is a $+C$ in answers, and it could change things. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JR9-dgU7tU) is video about a similar problem made by Numberphile.